# The "value" attribute of the HTML input tag doesn't show when using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is my HTML form section:

```
<input readonly="readonly" style="background-color:white" id="startdate" type="text" class="form-control" name="startdate" value="something">

<input readonly="readonly" style="background-color:white" id="enddate" type="text" class="form-control" name="enddate" value="somethingelse">
```

and this is the Javascript/Jquery that triggers the Datepicker (using daterange):

```
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    $('#startdate').datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
  }
});
$( "#enddate" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    $('#enddate').datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
  }
});
$('#startdate').datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
$('#enddate').datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
```

For some reason, the "value" attribute doesn't show in the browser despite being present on the HTML source.

Comment: Can you add it on jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know why it is happening but adding the format to the initialization fixes the problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HJbPd/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah it does. My last two rows break something, it seems. Thanks.

Comment: @VinayakPingale Works, but raw HTML doesn't seem to support ISO 8601

Answer (score 1):

The default `dateFormat` is `mm/dd/yy` ([see here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)). If you format your html values like that, they will show up. If you want a different format, you have to add a `dateFormat` option to the initialization `datepicker()`, or else the datepicker will remove the "invalid value", so when you call the `dateFormat` setters, the values are already empty.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. My solution:

```
function initializeDateField(selector)
{

    $(selector).datepicker($.datepicker.regional["pl"]).datepicker("option", {  
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      autoSize: true
    });

    $(selector).each(function() {
      $( this ).datepicker("setDate", $(this).attr('value'));
    });

}
```

`initializeDateField` is method for datepicker initialization. After initialization I iterate on selector result and force `setDate` manually.

I use `attr()` not `val()` because `val()` returns empty string when datepicker is initialized.
My HTML form is dynamic so I have to make solution to refresh date value dynamicaly too.

Hope helps to you.